# recycler view returns empty textview from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase. I have done the exact steps for another data and it worked perfectly. But I can't seem to get it right with products.

Here is my codes :

product model

```
public class ProductModel {
    private String name;
    private String price;
    private String description;


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

}
```

product adapter

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder>  {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<ProductModel> list;

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProductModel> list){
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_one,parent,false);
        return new ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder(v);    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ProductModel productModel = list.get(position);

        holder.description.setText(productModel.getName());
        holder.price.setText(productModel.getPrice());
        holder.description.setText(productModel.getDescription());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ProductViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView name, description, price;


        public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productName);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);

        }
    }
}
```

product list

```
public class ProductList extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ProductAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<ProductModel> list;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.product_list);

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("products");

    recyclerView =  findViewById(R.id.productList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ProductAdapter(this,list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                ProductModel product = dataSnapshot.getValue(ProductModel.class);
                list.add(product);
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

tabone.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.tablayout.Fragments.TabOne">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=" Name :"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/productName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:text="Arya"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=" Price:"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:text="Stark"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Description :"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:text="18"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

product_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ui.Operations.ProductList">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/productList">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I saved the data manually just for testing. [Here is how my firebase looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8dqF.png) The output is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhkEc.png) . Text there was manually written so they are not being overwritten with data in firebase. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat? Besides that, have you tried kboskin's solution? Does it work?

Comment: I have tried logging, but it doesnt print. I did try his solution but no luck

Comment: Is `products` a direct child of the root node?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to debug without having full access but it seems that in your adapter there are some hardcoded things right now

```
 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

Try changing that to be

```
 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size;
}
```

So that when you call notify adapter, it doesn't operate with hardcoded 0 lengths. I would also recommend you updating the adapter using some custom method, so that data from the original list doesn't mixed data in adapter

Comment: Thanks for the reply I fixed the return part, but the output didn't change. I couldn't understand what you meant by using custom method. If you need any more details i can provide you @kboskin

Comment: Could you please put the log into the onDataChange? Next thing I would check if you really need a loop there. I believe onDataChange should be called times objects you have

Comment: Logs are not printing anything, i tried to solve this too but no luck. Tried using no loops, again no luck

Comment: @dun are you sure there is no white spaces in the path or something like that? If listener isn't called -> means there is no data in that place. So, I believe it might be wrong node name